# Thread.sleep() proving superior to implicitlyWait

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I have a lot of Thread.sleep() commands in my java selenium webdriver project. I have read often and again that using the sleep command is a bad practice and implicitlyWait command should instead be declared once after a browser instance is launched and it will take care of the whole script. This is not working for me on this project.

As There are a lot of NoSuchElementExceptions being thrown for certain elements, I added a sleep command just before each element that poses a problem. The script passed. When I took off the sleep commands and declared implicitlyWait 30 seconds, script failed with a WebdriverException/NoSuchElementException as webdriver is unable to find each of those elements. Sleep command is finding the elements in 2 or 3 seconds. Is Thread.sleep() proving superior here? If I have to use ExplicitlyWait, then I have to declare a lot of them also, as there are many elements that require expected conditions. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

**Thread.sleep()** - Set each time you want to wait. A "dumb" wait. It waits for the time specified, no more, no less. If your element is available in 25ms, it will still wait the 10s that you specified leading to wasted time each run.

**Implicit wait** - Set once and persists throughout the life of the `WebDriver` instance. It waits for the specified time for *every* `.findElement()` call. So if you ever need to check that an element does not exist, etc. then your check will wait for the time specified in the implicit wait which also leads to wasted time.

**Explicit wait** (`WebDriverWait`) - Set each time you want a wait. This is just a specific instance of a `FluentWait`. It is customizable with all the common needs (visible, clickable, etc.) using `ExpectedConditions`. This is the best practice.

**Fluent wait** - Set each time you want a wait. The Swiss Army knife of waits. Can do anything... is fully customizable. Can be useful in very specific instances but generally most of your wait needs will be covered by `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions`.

**How I use waits...**

I use the page object model and in the constructor for each page object that is run when a page is loading, I use a `WebDriverWait` to wait for an element on the page to be available. Once that element is available, I know that the full page is loaded. Now I can scrape whatever elements I want off the page. If I ever change the state of the page, I have another `WebDriverWait` to wait for a new element to appear which signals that the dynamic page change has finished. Now I can scrape at will again.

You really shouldn't need to wait for *every* `.findElement()` call. Wait for the page to load or wait for a dynamic page change as I described above and you'll only need waits in very specific instances... not everywhere.

NOTE: [Do not mix implicit and explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). You will get bad/weird results.

Answer (score 1):

Use explicit wait for your element to locate. It will wait till the condition or the maximum wait time provided before throwing the Exception.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriverRefrence,20); // pass time in seconds as much you need
WebElement myElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("your element's id")));
```

**Note:**
FluentWait may be another good option too.

Comment: the problem with explicit wait is that it is for individual cases. I cannot declare it one for all the elements concerned, so similar to Thread.sleep(), it would have to be declared numerous times in the script. Correct?